# Developed apps-script for another user -- how to prevent access to my docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-account

I have developed a spreadsheet and an attached apps script, and installed it in another user's drive. The script also has access to a form and a doc in his drive.

There is a trigger that runs a function in that script.

After the development was complete, I made him the owner of the files.

Question: What are the steps I must take to make sure that the script will never have access to my drive? I'm looking for a water-tight, fool proof checklist.

For example, I have removed the trigger that I created from my account and requested him to set up a trigger under his account.

So are there any other steps of this kind that I need to take?

Comment: Are you the owner of the spreadsheet file?  Who is the owner of the spreadsheet file?

Comment: After development I made the other user the owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could revoke all access rights you have given to that script. Got to Google, click on your profile picture in the upper right corner and select "my account". Then click on "connected apps & sites" and then on "manage apps".